# Jquery, get values from <li> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-sortable

I have list with id `myid`. I can get values li values like this `$('#' + i).text()`. But I am using `$( '#myid' ).sortable()` . How can get values in currently displayed order? [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/rcmyy/58/). I need to implement function in `stop:`

```
<ul id='myid'>
    <li id='1'>value 1</li>
    <li id='2'>value 2</li>
    <li id='3'>value 3</li>
    <li id='4'>value 4</li>
    <li id='5'>value 5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.each()` with `.text()`  : **[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rcmyy/60/)**

```
stop:function(){
        $('li',this).each(function(){
            alert($(this).text())
        });
    }
```

or `map()` to get them into array.

```
stop:function(){
        var $li= $('li',this).map(function(){
            return $(this).text()
        });
        alert($li)
    }
```